# How to fuse rows in Pentaho Kettle

Tags: oracle, mongodb, pentaho

So, I'm moving an Oracle DB to a Mongo DB. I have a collection called Work, where all films, painting and the rest are stocked. I also have a collection called Authority, where all people that ever interacted with one work are (actors, painter, etc.) I'm trying to make a link between Authorities and Works inside the Work collection this way:

```
"workCS": {
   "casting": [
        {
            "authority": ObjectID("anID"),
            "role": [
                "actor",
                "realisator"
            ]
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "authority": ObjectID("otherID"),
            "role": [
                "actor"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So, I know how to make a manyToMany joint in Pentaho Kettle, so I had no problem making the basic structure of the collection. However, I can't find a way to make the role table inside the casting table, and end up with something like this:

```
"workCS": {
   "casting": [
        {
            "authority": ObjectID("anID"),
            "role": [
                "actor"
            ]
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "authority": ObjectID("anID"),
            "role": [
                "realisator"
            ]
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "authority": ObjectID("otherID"),
            "role": [
                "actor"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Which is incoherent with the post treatment we do to our data.

When I make my SQL to get the data from the Oracle DB, I have something like this:

```
"id"; "LastName"; "FirstName"; "Role";
1; "Radcliffe"; "Daniel"; "Actor";
1; "Radcliffe"; "Daniel"; "Writer"; 
2; "Grint"; "Rupert"; "Actor";
```

Is there a way to fuse rows in Pentaho, so this example is displayed this way?

```
"id"; "LastName"; "FirstName"; "Roles";
1; "Radcliffe"; "Daniel"; "Actor, Writer";
2; "Grint"; "Rupert"; "Actor";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The step you are looking for is the `Group by`, with and `Aggregation` type of `Concatenate strings separated by ,` on the roles.

You need to specify the other three columns as keys in the `Group field`, because even though the only real key is the Authority_id, if you do not specify them as group field, they will disappear.

Also use the `Memory Group by`,unless you have really, really a lot of rows, in which case use the `Group by` and make sure the data is sorted by Authority_id (they will automatically also sorted by Names).

[image]